# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hover' of null IP.Board

Tags: jquery

i made animated jQuery hover. But i have error in console and script dont work.

**HTML**

```
     <div id="formNav" class="sotwFormNav">
        <div class="currWeek"><a href="{parse url="module=sotw&section=view&year={$year}&week={$week}" base="publicWithApp"}">« Głosuj na najlepsze zrzuty</a></div>
        <div class="currWeek"><a id="upload" onclick="sotwUpload(1);" href="#">Wrzuć własny zrzut ekranu »</a></div>
     </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$.noConflict();
$('#formNav div').hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).stop(true, false).fadeTo('fast', 1);
}, function() {
    jQuery(this).stop(true, false).fadeTo('fast', 0.65);
});
```

Code (IP.Board template): http://pastebin.com/uM0V99rW

Comment: Next time include your html and javascript instead of posting a link

Comment: Use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) instead of pastebin

Comment: You shouldn't ever be calling `$.noConflict()`. When you actually **need** to use that function there's no guarantee that `$` refers to `jQuery`. You should always be calling `jQuery.noConflict()`.

Answer (score 1):

Once you call `$.noConflict()`, the `$` character is no longer jQuery (see [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)), so your use of `$('#formNav div')` will not yield a jQuery object, therefore `hover()` is not defined there.

The point of `noConflict()` is to remove conflicts with other javascript libraries, like Prototype and MooTools, that define  `$` as a global variable. If you don't use another library that defines `$`, you don't need to use `noConflict()`

So either remove the `$.noConflict()` line, or for every subsequent call using `$`, replace `$` with `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('#formNav div').hover(function(){
```

to

```
jQuery('#formNav div').hover(function(){
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TNBgk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

As has been previously mentioned, the point of the `jQuery.noConflict()` is to set `$` back to whatever value it had prior to jQuery being loaded. In a lot of cases that will be nothing, and as a result trying to use it to select elements won't return anything.

One solution is to only use `jQuery.noConflict()` when necessary (i.e. when you're loading another JavaScript framework that also uses `$` as a shortcut), and also replace every instance of `$` with `jQuery` in your code.

However, there's another option, and that's to create a closure where `$` refers to jQuery inside of it, but still refers to whatever else (possibly nothing) outside:

```
(function($) {
    $('#formNav div').hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).stop(true, false).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).stop(true, false).fadeTo('fast', 0.65);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This is the same pattern that (most) jQuery plugins use as it allows `$` to be used a shortcut for `jQuery` without worrying about conflicts with other frameworks.